# Django Website multi-language

Tags: django, session, translation, multilingual

this is obviously a highly discussed topic already, but I am struggling with the answers I found on Google and here on StackOverflow.

I have implemented the models for enabling multiple languages, that works perfectly fine. My problem is to allow the user on the website to change the language permanently for themselves.

I am having a language flag in the top menu bar which the user can click to change the language. It then opens /setlanguage/de, whereas de is the language. en for English etc.

```
def setlanguage(request, lang):
    defaultLanguage = 'en'
    try:
        if 'language' in request.session:
            pass
    except KeyError:
        request.session['language'] = defaultLanguage

    if defaultLanguage == lang:
        return redirect("/")

    if lang not in list(Language.objects.all().values_list('code').distinct()):
        request.session['language'] = defaultLanguage
    else:
        request.session['language'] = lang

    return redirect('/')
```

The reason this does not work is the redirect and that I cannot set any variables on the request.

However, I only really have one single page anyways, so I only need to redirect the user to "/". 
My translations also support different slugs in the URL.

```
url(r'^show/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)', views.show, name='show'),
```

So that I can do ajax requests to "/page/easy-to-use" or "/page/einfach-zu-bedinen" to get the same page.

I do not really want to set a cookie on the user's computer. I come from a PHP background, I assume the session handling works slightly different in Django, as I would expect to have it available globally rather than on a per request basis?

Is there a work around to not use session, but to just reload the page with the selected language without clustering up the source code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use built into django set_language view?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#set-language-redirect-view

Also: what's the point of

```
try:
    if 'language' in request.session:
        pass
```

this literally does nothing.

Checking if lang is available doing this:

```
    if lang not in list(Language.objects.all().values_list('code').distinct()):
```

Is not good, because you every time fetching all languages from database. Better scenario is:

```
    if Language.objects.filter(code=lang):
```

Consider putting available languages into settings.py file instead of database. If you really want to store it in database, synchronize it somehow with `settings.LANGUAGES` somehow, so all django built in and third party modules can take advantage of it.

Comment: Thank you! This is some very helpful information. For the first code snippet, because of the request problem, I received error pages, because of the KeyError, this way I could bypass that problem. The second code snippet: I don't trust User input, and since it could be malicious I do not want to put it into a database query. I know DJango takes care of SQL Injection, but somehow I don't trust that. I do see your performance concern though! And I agree, I wasn't happy either with that solution. I guess, settings file it is !

Comment: First of all, if you are switching into django from PHP, forget about SQL injection unless you are using raw SQL (whole statement or it fragments). ORM takes care of it and you shouldn't do it again. Secondly: first snippet actually does nothing. If you have `if X in Y:` it will NEVER throw KeyError, because if operator is for checking if key is present. So you're again doing something twice.

Comment: Ok, nice. I appreciate your help! I will fix that and don't produce such nonsense again :)